# Drag and Drop not dropping

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am a trying to use JS to drag an drop nodes on a family tree. However, the nodes will drag, but will not drop where they are placed. They return to their orginal position.

I am not sure if I am defining the area where they can be dropped correctly.
The JS code is:

```
function allowDrop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("img");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

I then inserted a DIV within a HTML section to allow the drop:

```
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Then the HTML code to allow elements to be dragged:

```
<a  title="No Info "draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" href="DiggaDiary1.html" id="shadow" href="#">++ Annie Johnson 1781-(Tuam)</a>
            <ul>
```

Thanks
Ciaran

Comment: two things:1. event does not exist, so you can't pass it, 2. you set "Text" data but get "img" from the event dataTransfer, they should be identical.

Comment: @dandavis What do you mean, "event does not exist"?

Comment: i mean ondragstart="drag(event)" points to a global variable, event, that is not defined in the code shown.

Comment: I kind of want to edit this title to just say "Dragging."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, however you are setting 'text' not 'img' in your dragstart so make it like below :

```
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FMHjc/).

**Edit :**

you can also make it easier and do like below:

```
function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.srcElement;
    ev.target.appendChild(data);
}
```

Comment: Hey,I set the getData and setData arguments  as "a", still no joy, the node is still draggable anywhere on the window but wont drop.

Comment: This is the webpage, it may make things clearer: http://www.mooneycallans.com/mooneyTree2.html

Comment: Added the get and setData argument 'Text'; implemented code fix above, and the node drops! But when it 'drops' into the div the node is not visible, and the node is still present from its original drag position....

Comment: you probably need to add some processing to remove it from its parentElement and append it to the new parent using `removeElement()` and `appendChild()`

Comment: Hey, using the safari debugger I get the following error:  A node was inserted somewhere it doesnt belong. Ref: ev.target.appendChild(data);

Comment: almost got it, if I am to use removeElement() method/function?, is the  syntax ev.target.removeElement(document.getElementById(data));....I have the nodes dragging and dropping now except all parents, siblings and children of the dragged and dropped node move also (the entire tree)

Comment: That is nice where you able to fix it ?
You can take a look at this : http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_elements.asp

Comment: it should be `element.prentNode.removeElement(element);` and then `newParent.appendChild(element);`

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thanks for help, element.parentNode.removeElement(element); plus newParent.appendChild(element) worked